# In T3 Stack project, I'm getting query logs in console of browser, How can I stop it?

Tags: prisma, trpc, t3

I have T3 stack project and I'm fetching data using trpc and prisma, but It's showing logs in browsers console.[image]

How can I stop this logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have `loggerLink` enabled in your config, just check for it and pass `enabled: () => false` if you want to disable it, or just remove it completely.

```
export const trpc = createTRPCNext<AppRouter>({
  config() {
    return {
      links: [
        loggerLink({
          // Use whatever condition you want here
          enabled: (opts) => false,
        }),
      ],
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: Well, you have to post more details then, code examples and etc.

Comment: Actually thanks It works !, It's my bad that I was implementing it at wrong place.